# Error installing .bna file on ibm starter plan for blockchain

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

All these while I had been running my Hyperledger composer on AWS and it had been great so far with all the configurations setup.
But the starter plan has been launched by IBM like couple of days ago,
and I had tried following the configurations on the IBM website.

Upon reaching to the last/final step of deploying the .bna file to the network, 
I am too facing this problem with composer 0.18.2 where, Do hope there's a solution on what I am missing it out.

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute... Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT

Any help would be great, as this is fairly new to me, and it had sucked up couple of hours from me.

Answer (score 0):

The default timeout is 15s but on some systems, it is not sufficient. Try increasing the timeout value using:

`export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=30`

Comment: This start timeout is only relevant to the default development Fabric.  In the situation of this question the Fabric has already started, and there is a different timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Starter plan is currenlty compatible with composer 0.18.1 (not 0.81.2)

Suggestions for following 'deploying-a-business-networks-on-starter-plan'

Make sure you are running composer 0.18.1  (run composer -v and if not 0.18.1 run npm install -g composer-cli@0.18.1)

Run the sync command below after the status comment given in Step three, point 4.  Make sure the peer is running before issuing the sync command
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --basic --user ${USERID}:${PASSWORD} --data-binary '{}' ${API_URL}/api/v1/networks/${NETWORKID}/channels/${CHANNEL}/sync

If Step Five, point 2 (composer network start) fails with a timeout, it is recommended to wait a short while then try issuing the command again.

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Node version is up to date (8.10.0) as well as npm (5.6.0).

As noted above, Starter Plan in only compatible with Composer 0.18.1. First, uninstall composer cli completely

```
npm uninstall -g composer-cli
```

before installing Composer 0.18.1

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.18.1
```

After that, you can try running through the steps to deploy the .bna file to the network.