# Hyperledger Composer - Instantiation Chaincode Error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I'm currently using **HL Composer [v0.18.2]** to be able to interact with the **IBM** **Blockchain Platform (Starter Plan)** on IBM Cloud.
I executed the following steps:

1. Created 4 Organization with 1 peer for each one
2. Created a new channel
3. Joined the channel, created the PeerAdmin Identity, updated the certificate and sync the channel (for each organization)
4. Installed a runtime for each peer of each organization

But when I try to start the network with `"composer network start ...."` i'm getting this error:

```
Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to instantiate composer runtime. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: instantiation policy violation: signature set did not satisfy policy)
```

Does anyone have an idea about the problem?
Thanks

Comment: Please answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49483203/error-installing-bna-file-on-ibm-starter-plan-for-blockchain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starter Plan is only compatible with Composer v0.18.1

First, uninstall Composer completely

```
npm uninstall -g composer-cli
```

Then, install Composer v0.18.1

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.18.1
```

Now, take the steps for deploying your .bna as before. If the problem persists, ensure you have the latest version of Node (v8.10.0) and npm (5.6.0).